# Wrapping a Block in a Block of the Same Type

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I have a chain of objects. Objects along the chain exist to nicely divide functionality. A completion block gets passed up the chain, and I thought if another object wanted to add stuff to the completion block, I could just wrap the completion block in a block of the same type, calling the first block, and everything would be aces. I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Is my syntax wrong or am I approaching this in the wrong way entirely?

```
-(void)archiveChatWithDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dictionary andCompletionBlock:(ServerConnectionCompletionBlock)completionBlock
{
    ServerConnectionCompletionBlock localCompletionBlock = ^(ServerConnection *connection, NSError *error) {

        // Do some stuff
        // ...

        //  This line produces EXC_BAD_ACCESS
        completionBlock(connection, error);
    };    

    [self.chatEndpointInterface archiveChatWithDictionary: dictionary andCompletionBlock: localCompletionBlock];
}
```

Comment: Is the call to `archiveChatWithDictionary:andCompletionBlock:` calling the same method (i.e. as opposed to a method with the same name but different implementation in another class). If so, you might have infinite recursion.

Comment: Yes it's an ARC project, no the method is not calling itself.

Comment: @NickLocking: can you post the code for the method that is called from here? it could be something wrong there

Answer (score 3):

In the end, is the completionBlock copied (or inlined in a block that is copied)?

By default, blocks are stored on the stack. If you want to keep a block around (generally for a completion block), you have to copy it (so it moves to the heap).

The good thing is that if you copy a block, all nested blocks will be copied as well.

Comment: It doesn't matter what happens "in the end". Apple's memory management is purely local. A function should only care what it does, not what other functions do. He is doing nothing in that function that requires a copy. He is not storing it away anywhere that will persist after the function call.

Comment: That was not my point and I was not pointing to that particular function but to the underlying one that actually stores the block.

Comment: Okay, can you be more specific that it does not need to be copied in that function; but in a function that stores the block (if there is such a function)?

Answer (score 0):

I am doing the exactly same thing and it is working perfectly.

I did get that crash though, and it turned out that **the wrapped block was nil**. Perhaps you could check that out.

I recommend asserting that the block is not nil or putting an if-statement before the block call, depending on your particular situation.